# How can I restore email from my "Junk email" folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007, spam-prevention

I'm using Outlook 2007.

I check my "Junk Email" folder ~once a month. This time I found that my whole Google Groups correspondence is there.

I right-clicked a message and pressed "Add sender to safe senders list". Hopefully, the future messages to this group will be delivered to my inbox. The problem is with the messages that are already in the junk folder.

Is there a way to resort my junk folder automatically, to have emails from senders listed on my safe list being recovered from the junk folder and moved to the Inbox folder for example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can restore this from the webmail on Gmail.com.  Log in to your Gmail account and look in the junk mail box.  I believe you can restore or move items from there.  Also, check your junk folder (in Outlook) and simply drag and drop that folder (or individual messages) into your inbox or wherever you want to move them.